# HTML document stucture checker

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes, document

I'm making a template editor in AngularJS 1.5.x/Typescript. The editor takes a html template string from an API and then parses the string with DOMParser, the result is a Document Object that allows me to manipulate its structure with the Javascript built-in API DOM, jQuery, Xpath, etc...

But before this process, I want to check if the incoming HTML Template Structure is correct according to and existing Document Structure.

For example:

```
DOCUMENT STRUCTURE DEFINITION
document
|__ body
    |__div@data-container-app
       |__div.@data-module-1
       |__div.@data-module-2
       |__div.@data-module-3
```

I need to compare the HTML template structure with the above scheme and determinate if the template structure is correct, to proceed.

I knows that in XML exists an DTD but my question is: is there something like this but for HTML or exists some library that it can realize this process?.

Comment: if the templates are syntactically valid html, just run them through a dom parser?